# Problems using getElementsByClassName with createHTMLDocument

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm having problems with getElementsByClassName against an object built through createHTMLDocument. Prior to trying createHTMLDocument I had createElement('div') and this worked fine, but not so when createHTMLDocument

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('Starting...');

  //var copy = document.createElement('div');
  var copy = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('virtual');
  copy.innerHTML = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
  //console.log(copy.innerHTML);
  var r = copy.getElementsByClassName('removeOnSave');
  console.log('seen ' + r.length);
  for (var i = r.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) r[i].parentNode.removeChild(r[i]);
  var contentsTx = copy.innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('output').value = contentsTx;

}, 1000);
```

```html
<h3>Load HTML from some content while trying not to trigger network calls</h3>

    <div id="test">
        Lorem ipsum
        <img src="https://cdn.speakerscorner.co.uk/files/media/public/image/richard-ayoade-xsq.jpg">
        Lorem ipsum <div class="removeOnSave">REMOVE ME</div>
    </div>
    
    
    <textarea id="output" style="width:100%; height:200px"></textarea>
```

(A JSFiddle demonstrator is also available on https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/deg3846s/10/)

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you shod set `innerHTML` on the body of the newly created document i.e. `copy.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;`. I think you are able to explain yourself why, so I won't explain in details.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('Starting...');

  //var copy = document.createElement('div');
  var copy = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('virtual');
  copy.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
  //console.log(copy.innerHTML);
  var r = copy.getElementsByClassName('removeOnSave');
  console.log('seen ' + r.length);
  for (var i = r.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) r[i].parentNode.removeChild(r[i]);
  var contentsTx = copy.body.innerHTML;
  console.log('contentsTx=',contentsTx );
  document.getElementById('output').value = contentsTx;

}, 1000);
```

```html
<h3>Load HTML from some content while trying not to trigger network calls</h3>

    <div id="test">
        Lorem ipsum
        <img src="https://cdn.speakerscorner.co.uk/files/media/public/image/richard-ayoade-xsq.jpg">
        Lorem ipsum <div class="removeOnSave">REMOVE ME</div>
    </div>
    
    
    <textarea id="output" style="width:100%; height:200px"></textarea>
```

Comment: Change `var contentsTx = copy.innerHTML;` to `var contentsTx = copy.body.innerHTML` otherwise your solution will show undefined

Comment: thanks, just fixed the part where `.removeOnSave` tag is not found, because that was the question, but you are right that a few lines bellow a new one will appear.